# Big bang and time

Tags: cosmology, time, big-bang, popular-science

I heard Carl Sagan talking about the Universe 15 Billion years ago, and the Big Bang.  He made the statement that it was the biggest explosion of all time (at first I thought this a subtle pun).  This leads me to my question.  What would time have been like at +1 "moment" after the big bang?  What I'm trying to ask is, and I hate to say it because I'm afraid I'll sound foolish, did time flow at the same rate?  Wouldn't all that mass in one place have distorted space/time (and why didn't it "rip" it)?

If I were inside of that mass with a stop watch, I'm guessing I wouldn't have been able to measure a difference because time would have effected me the same way as it effected all the other space/mass in the area.  I'm guessing I would have to have something inside (the initial Big Bang mass) and something outside measuring time and see if there was a difference (intuitively this feels weird to consider, could I actually place something "outside" the "Big Bang mass").

Maybe I've said too much, or made the question too complicated.  I apologize if this is the case.

### Update

A black hole is a lot of Mass collapsed into a small space.  I believe that as mass increases time dilation increases.  I remember hearing that if you fell into a black hole, you'd never experience the last second of your life...

If this is true of black holes, how did time pass in the mass/energy that is responsible for the big bang?  As the big bang occurred, did time speed up with the expansion of the universe?  I'm trying to explain what I'm getting at by asking more questions related to what I was asking.  I'm trying to understand what time itself looked like.  As I understand it time prevents everything from happening at once.  If time was a line, were the ends smashed together into a point before the Big Bang ?  Maybe as mass/energy expanded the "time line" expanded too?

Comment: While you've got the seed of a interesting idea (distortions of spacetime in the immediate aftermath of the big bang), I don't think this is really a well-defined question. You've kind of identified the reason why: there's no way to place something outside the universe to compare it with what's in the universe, as you're asking about.

Comment: I have to agree with David on his comment here.

Comment: Thanks for keeping your question active, Everett - perhaps we can improve it into something we can answer. Maybe this will help: there's a lot of philosophical speculation about what time really is, but we don't deal with that here. In physics, time is just a coordinate, like distance, height, or latitude or longitude. Just as different observers can measure distance differently, they can also measure time differently. That's what time dilation is. So if you want to ask a meaningful question about time dilation, you generally need to identify two specific observers and two specific events.

Comment: I think I may have used the wrong term.  Thank you for your patience with me, I really want to understand this.  Let me go back to the sentence with the word dilation in it, and restate it.  As mass increases a change occurs in the flow of time.  That was what I meant to say.  More to follow, saving edit...

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is this.  If a black hole is so massive, that gravity can effect particles moving at the speed of light, and cause an effect on space time, how did time ever pass in the mass energy that was the big bang making there be a "next moment" where the big bang occurred?  I'm only comparing this to black holes because it is something that has a lot of mass energy that currently exists in the known universe.

Comment: Can I compare the passage of time, at different points in time, instead of at the same time, at different points in space?  And if I did that, would time flow faster or slower at 1 "moment" after the big bang as opposed to one "moment" now?

Comment: I'm REALLY trying to stick with physics definitions, and avoid anything philosophical in my question.

Comment: General relativity lets you float around with different definitions of things, in such a way that it's really hard to answer this without getting into philosophical issues.  The standard way of writing down the cosmological solution to Einstein's equations involves choosing a special time coordinate that prevents any dialation-style events from being manifest.  But see my answer below.

Comment: It was stated earlier "In physics, time is just a coordinate, like distance, height, or latitude or longitude" which I agree with, and THINK I understand.  A coordinate goes with dimensionality.  If you have 0 dimensions you only have 1 point.  If everything was compressed (mass/energy and space/time), then the dimension of time was compressed with the space dimensions?  If time dimensionality got compressed enough, would the beginning and end be touching?  Sorry for the primitiveness of my understanding.

Comment: That's certainly not the normal way of thinking of it.  Generally, you write down the four-metric as $ds^{2}=-dt^{2} + a(t)^{2}\left(\gamma_{ij}dx^{i}dx^{j}\right)$, where the $\gamma_{ij}$ is a time-independent spatial metric. Thus, the easy way of thinking of the problem is to imagine the spatial dimensions getting really small and the time 'flowing' at the same rate.  But that is just a special choice of time coordinate, and you can choose others to give the metric a different form.  It's more relevant to think of a problem like this in terms of what I"m trying to measure THEN interpreting.

Comment: Now I know why I'm not a Physicist, I have to do it bassackwards ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sense in which this can be answered a bit unambiguously--it is a known effect that gravitational fields both dilate time, by a factor $\sqrt{1-\frac{2\,G\,M}{c^{2}\,r}}$ and redshift light waves by that same factor.

It is also known that cosmological effects redshift gravitational waves.  This time, it is done by a factor of $a(t)$, the so-called 'radius of the universe'.  For example, the cosmic microwave background radiation was believed to have been radiated from a surface whose temperature (and therefore, emitted wavelength) is roughly equivalent to the surface of a hot star.  It is a matter of simple algebra to find a value of $\frac{M}{r}$ for which the two effects are roughly equivalent, and, if you wish, you can think of this as describing a "different rate of time flow."

To my knowledge, there really isn't a useful reason to do this, though.

Comment: I usually hear $a(t)$ called the "scale factor" which I think is a bit more accurate than "radius."

Comment: Both terms are used---I see 'radius of the universe' more often in popular literature.  In a closed cosmological model, the spatial section is a 3-sphere, and the radius is literally $a(t)$.  Older researchers loathed boundary conditions in GR,and so there was a collective hope that the universe was closed.    We now know that the closed model is almost certainly not our universe, but some people still say 'radius of the universe'.  The question seemed non-technical enough that I stuck with the most common non-technical term in my answer.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer. No, a(t) is not the radius of the universe, it is the scale factor. It is defined as 1 NOW, and to get distances you have to integrate. Since radius of the universe in most definitions is some of horizon distance, there are various definitions. The particle horizon is 46 Gly (about 14 Gpsec) away, the Hubble horizon is  about 4 Gpsec and the event horizon about 5 Gpsecs. See            https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cosmological_horizons. The particle horizon is from integrating over conformal time dt/a, and the others are different definitions and measures.

Comment: @BobBee: it is common to refer to $a$ as the radius of the universe, and in the case of closed cosmological models, this is literally true (assuming an inherited unit from the spatial variables)

Comment: There is a lot of measures of what is the size or radius of the universe. I've never seen them referred to as a. So which definition of radius does it use?

Comment: @BobBee: it's books using evocative langauge.  In the case of a closed universe, the spatial sections of the universe are literally 3-spheres with radius $a$.  Back in the day, the closed model was favored as the "most likely" model, so most books treated this one most seriously, and inherited the term "radius of the universe"

Comment: Back in the day, not now. There's too many horizons. And it applies also to closed universes, you just change lambda a little and it closes it

Comment: @BobBee: in a closed universe, $a$ is the literal radius of the universe.  Not the radius of the visible universe, or the particle horizon.  The radius of the 3-sphere.  You might not like that that's a term commonly used in some relativity texts, but it's there.  And is kind of ancillary to the answer anyway.

Comment: Well, I agree on the last statement. Can you give me a ref where a is used as the radius?

Comment: @BobBee: see the wikipedia article on the FRW metric: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric .  In particular:  "Then r is unitless and a(t) has units of length. When k = ±1, a(t) is the radius of curvature of the space, and may also be written R(t)."

Comment: Yes, ok, I see it. Sorry for the doubts. Just so much easier to use scale factor for a, and define it as 1 now, and not model dependent, while distances and all else are model and observationally dependent. But ok. And physically it is all equivalent, as you stated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In the context of FRW cosmology, there is no difference in the rate of time between the epochs of the evolution of the universe. You can see that from the form of the line element

$$ds^2=-dt^2+a(t)^2\gamma_{ij}dx^idx^j.$$

That is a result of the symmetries that you assume for the matter distribution (homogeneous, isotropic) and the choice of observers that you make. So the observers that follow the expansion of the Universe, which are the galaxies more or less, perceive the same time wherever and whenever they are. The cosmological time is the proper time of all the comoving observers, as it is evident from the line element.

In the case of a Schwarzschild metric and static observers

$$ds^2=-(1-\frac{2M}{r})dt^2+(1-\frac{2M}{r})^{-1}dr^2+r^2d\Omega^2,$$

it is the factor in front of dt that makes the difference and you have different time rates for observers at different positions.

There is one more point. Someone mentions the redshift and the perceived difference of the rate of time for faraway objects. That would appear to contradict what I am saying, but it isn't. The redshift effect is an observer symmetric effect. Like in the case of SR where you have two inertial observers with different velocities and each of them thinks that the others time runs slower, when both of them actually experience proper time. That is very different from the case of the static observers near a gravitating object, where there is no such symmetry. The clock of the observer that is at bigger r runs faster than the clock of the one that is at smaller r.

Comment: But, I could define a set $\{T(t,r),R(t,r)\}$ such that $g_{TT}=1, \,G_{TR}=0$.  Sure, it would make the rest of the metric time-dependent and messy, but there's no abstract reason why I can't do it (It's two PDE's for two variables, after all, and would be equivalent to setting $\alpha=1,\,\beta_{r}=0$ in an ADM IVBP of the problem).

Comment: Are you talking about the Schw. metric? If you do that, then you are making a different choice of observers and you are measuring time with respect to their proper time (these observers are probably the freefalling ones). The Schw. metric in its usual form is written with respect to the static observers at infinity. In any case, the physical picture wouldn't change.

Comment: By the way, these observers (freefalling) wouldn't perceive any difference in the rate of time as they fell towards the r=0 of the Schw. spacetime.

Comment: And there is one more point. In Schw. you can't define a global class of such observers. You would have to distinguish in different classes the observers that begin their freefall from different distances. On the other hand, you don't have a restriction like that in the case of the FRW comoving observers.

Comment: Yes-the Schwarzschild metric.  The metric you wrote down only covers 1/4 of the extended Kruskal spacetime, anyway-you're cutting off part of the spacetime by choosing the generator of the timelike Killing vector of the spacetime as a coordinate.  My point is that you can't make an argument based upon the form that metric components take-their definition is arbitrary.  The way to answer questions like this is to ask for what you're measuring first, calculating THAT, and THEN interpreting the answer.  It leads to error much less than 'time dilation' and 'frame dragging' and such terms.

Comment: And yes, my whole point is that if you write down the Schwarzschild metric in Novikov coordinates: http://godel.ph.utexas.edu/Members/2bh/novikov/novikov.html, then you don't see an explicit 'redshift' term in the metric--you have to find it by solving the null geodesic equation.

Comment: What I am saying is that the form of the metric is indicative of the class of observers you choose. In the case of the Schw metric in the standard form (I am only considering the exterior of a spherical mass) you have chosen a class of static observers and that is the more natural one in the sense that we are them measuring things on the surface of a spherical mass. In the case of cosmology, the natural class of observers are the comoving ones, since galaxies (us) are comoving observers. Thus the measured time is our proper time which doesn't change. Of course there is no absolute time.

Comment: There ${\bf is}$ no natural class of observers--all observers are equivalent.  You can choose a certain class to make Killing vectors obvious, or you can choose them to hide/show horizons, or whatever, but there is no preferred set of coordinates.  And you should be careful when talking about 'observers' when you are talking about changes of coordinate systems, anyway.  That interpretation of things is much more natural in a tetrad formalism, where the local Minkowski frames are made explicit.  And tetrads are {\bf still} generally covariant on their spacetime indices.

Comment: I agree 100%. I didn't say that there is a preferred set of coordinates in the sense of an absolute set of coordinates. But there are frames that are more natural than others. I can have a description in any coordinate frame and all possible choices would be equivalent. But for cosmology, there is a natural frame, that of the comoving observers. It is not natural because it is special from a physical point of view (a preferred set of coordinates), but it is special because it is our frame, it is the frame of the galaxies. So that is the frame we use to describe what we see.

Comment: Ok, but going back to the original topic, the 'perception of time', defined locally, is meaningless due to the equivalence principle.  A clock, placed anywhere, will tick "normally" relative to local observers.  The only discussion we can have about this is when you compare different observers.  And those comparisons don't have anything to do with how we choose to render the metric.  Define me the two timelike curves, and I can tell you how to calculate their relative time flow rate, in ANY coordinate system.  It's merely convenient to choose a family of surfaces comoving with both.

Comment: Well, that’s the point. The cosmological comoving observers, because of the symmetry that you have in that particular frame (the universe is homogenous and isotropic in that frame), can be defined to occupy a spatial slice that spans the entire universe and has a global notion of time which is the proper time of these observers. Thus you don’t only have o global notion of time, but you also have the same rate of time in every instance in the history of these observers, regardless of the curvature of the spacetime.

Comment: If you now try to compare clock rates between two observers, you will see a respective redshift in the rate from the one clock to the other. But that is an effect that has to do with the rate of change of the scale factor. If on the other hand both observers try to calculate the age of the universe, they will both find the same age. If they try to measure the rate of change of their clocks measuring of time (let’s say by an ideal experiment of measuring the drift in the frequency of a photon that was emitted from a particular transition from a particular atom) they will find a null result.

Comment: I don't even think we are even disagreeing on anything but interpretation here.  Except that I don't think your second experiment means anything, once again, since the only time along a geodesic is proper time, which, by definition, progresses at the same rate relative to itself as you move forward.  You would get a null result in a general spacetime.  The experiment that both observers (now separated in space) would agree on is "I saw YOUR clock ticking at X rate at Y time after the Big bang", with equal values for X and Y.  But that's hardly a satisfactory answer to the OP.

Comment: I don't think we are essentially disagreeing either. My second experiment intended to show that if the rate of time was changing then the frequency of the preserved photon would drift and if compared with a new photon from the same transition would be of different frequency. Maybe it was a bad idea for an experiment. But my point is as you say, since the cosmological time is the proper time of the observers that follow the Hubble flow, it has the same rate all the time and for all the observers of that class.

Comment: An other way to put it, and I hope that this will make it clear, is that if the universe were closed, at the moment of the Big Crunch, all the observers would be on time, they would all shake hands and agree on the age of the universe.

Comment: :)  I think we've pedantized enough.  An upvote and a handshake.

Comment: :) Nice talking to you.

Answer (score -1):

1. First, let us suppose you have the energy to travel at any speed you like. The only restriction you have is that you cannot travel at the speed of light, because you would need infinite energy, and even though you have infinite energy, you cannot apply infinite energy if you don't have infinite time to apply it.

So you accelerate in a ship let us say at 0.999C. Then you escape in a pod with infinite energy again from the ship that is already travelling at 0.999C. And you are leaving earth, by the way.

The question: Can you double your speed?

In other words, if you measure your speed from the escape pod, can you measure twice the speed you are travelling in the ship?

The answer is YES!!!

You can always double your measured speed. Even though there is a speed limit, namely C, measured from earth, the ship that is travelling gets its clocks stopped, so when they measure the speed, they all see an increase of speed.

Eventually you can get to the other side of the universe in a second, if you have enough energy and time to apply the energy for increased speed.

2. We all know that in a black hole, the time stops at the event horizon.

This means that if you fall into a black hole, your watch will be completely stopped when you enter into the event horizon, but it doesn't mean you will stop moving towards the center of the black hole.

Actually, you continue moving and you accelerate towards the center in free fall.

The interesting thing is that the gravitation is making your clock go slower. When you enter the event horizon you watch is already frozen, but time can only move backwards once you are inside the event horizon.

This seems contradictory. Since you are falling and therefore moving inwards, since your clock is moving backward, you would see that instead you are moving far away from the center, as in a big bang.

3. Inside the black hole, if you try to move back out of the black hole using the technology mentioned in 1, you can always increase your speed. but you cannot escape the black  hole. The reason is that you can never reach the event horizon, even though from your point of view you can accelerate and double your speed every second, from the point of view of an external observer, you can never reach C, and therefore you can never reach the event horizon.

In other words, you can see that you can travel fast a lot of space, but the event horizon has moved to infinity, so a new universe has been created inside the black hole, avoiding you from ever reaching the event horizon.

Comment: It is not possible to double the speed infinitely in the way you are proposing, and certainly this procedure is not valid to make you reach any remote point on space in any time. If you are in a ship travelling at .9999c w.r.t. Earth, you can move w.r.t. the ship at .9999c, but your speed w.r.t Earth will still be a fraction of c. So you will not distance from earth much more faster; unless your energy is literally "infinite" in which case you will distance from Earth and the ship at equal speed: c.